# Use the parent directory from the symlink instead of where the directory actually resides on the filesystem

Tags: symlink, cd-command, csh

So let's set up the context. Two paths:

`/some/very/convoluted/path/name/the-wanted-directory`

`/myhome`

I create a symbolic link in `/myhome` and then `cd` into it:

```
/myhome $ ln -s /some/very/convoluted/path/name/the-wanted-directory .
/myhome $ cd the-wanted-directory
/myhome/the-wanted-directory $
```

However, when I `cd` back up:

```
/myhome/the-wanted-directory $ cd ..
/some/very/convoluted/path/name $
# Where am I? I'm lost! I want to get back to /myhome!
```

Basically, I do not want `cd ..` to follow the physical parent of the symbolic link.  What option do I set for this?  I am using `csh`, if that matters.

Comment: If using `tcsh` (I doubt you'd be using csh), look at the description of the `symlinks` variable in the man page.

Answer (score 4):

You can find out the value of `symlinks` variable with this:

```
$ set | less
```

To get the behavior I want:

```
$ set symlinks="ignore"
```

For more information see `man tcsh` and look for the section on the `symlinks` variable.

Comment: If you want to find out the current setting, don't scroll to all your `set`tings, but simply do `echo $symlinks`